# How can I get the server's timezone in a Craft plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, datetime, timezone

I'm setting up cron jobs from my plugin and I need to format the date in the server's time zone. It looks like Craft is overriding the timezone set in php.ini because PHP's `date_default_timezone_get()` always returns UTC. Is there another way to get the actual timezone set on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ini_get('date.timezone')`.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php